# One sorter function for sort generic collections

Tags: sorting, go

In my project I have many collection (slices) of different data types. Any particular collection should define fields it can sort by. I want to write one sort function and call it with user input (sort field and order) whenever collection should be sorted. I came up with the following boilerplate code (described only one type of collection, but for others it will be the same): https://gist.github.com/abonec/f1ee23a38e78ea48d470c39885de47ba

I have an interface `Sortable` for collections. Sortable should be passed to the `sortStats` with user input of sort field. If concrete implementation supports this type of sort it should return `sort.Interface` with corresponding interface.

Problem with many repeated implementations of `sort.Interface` where `Len()` and `Swap()` method is identical. Different is only `Less()`.

Is there any approach to get a rid of `Len()` and `Swap()` methods in this case or may be other approach to write generic sort function with dynamic sort field?

Comment: If `sort.Slice` does not work for you then the answer is no.

Comment: I need to change sort direction if need. For this I use a `sort.Reverse` which takes a `sort.Interface`. How to change sort direction with `sort.Slice` without writing different less functions for sort different directions?

Comment: Just implement `sort.Interface` and use `sort.Sort`/`sort.Reverse` as needed.

Comment: @Adrian it is exactly what my current code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for generics, which Go doesn't currently support. See [this FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics).

The Go team is working to [add generics to the language](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md) - it's a work in progress, and everyone is free to participate in the discussion. Once generics exist, they will provide the solution you seek here.

---

In the meantime, you could use [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate) or think of a slightly different design for your problem. Some code duplication is OK too, Go doesn't frown upon it as badly as some other languages.

Comment: I know about generics in go, and no, i don't looking for generics. I looking for less repetitive approach for sorting different collections.